# Calling two different controller methods(actions) on one button click

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

Is there any way to call, two different controller methods one button click in MVC, JQuery, Ajax. 
Any small help would be fine. Thank You.

Comment: Please Add your code attempts

Comment: Sorry, to attempt I need to know how to invoke two controller actions. This help I need. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

In that button click event You call one AJAX function using ng-click event
If you have to use Controller.js and Service.js for data flowing then you can call two controller methods in one button click event

Comment: ng-click is angular, isn't mentioned in the question.